# Hadoop Job class not found

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce, classpath

Hi I'm having trouble and I haven't been able to get help yet from similar threads.  I am doing an example of a hadoop job and I'm just trying to run it from the IDE right now.  Here is my source code

```
package org.myorg;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;


public class WordCount 
{

public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException
    {
       String line = value.toString().toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\p{Punct}|\\d","");
       StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
       while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) 
       {

           word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
           output.collect(word,  one);

       }// end while

    }// end public void map

}// end public static class Map


public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable>
{
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException
    {
        int sum = 0;
        while (values.hasNext())
        {
            sum+= values.next().get();
        }// end while

        output.collect(key, new IntWritable(sum));

    }// end public void reduce

}// end public static class Reduce

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    JobConf conf = new JobConf(org.myorg.WordCount.class);
    conf.setJobName("wordcount");

    conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);
    conf.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
    conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

    conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
    conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

    JobClient.runJob(conf);

    }// end main

}//end public class WordCount
```

Here is the exception I'm getting.  does anyone have any ideas?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Level
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.<clinit>(JobConf.java:362)
    at org.myorg.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Level
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, it is short of log4j's jar files. you should add the jar to your classpath.

Comment: Oh I will try this tomorrow.  I wonder how it knows I'm missing log4j jar, if it doesnt recognize the class?  Shouldn't it be throwing a compilation error?  I hope thats not an absurd question

Comment: That was it sir!  I got another exception.  But thanks for that help.

Comment: Because when you compile the source code, the IDE will import the reference about the log4j automatically or manually. But when you run the program,   the IDE will  use it's own classpath usually, and if log4j isn't on the classpath, the exception "NoClassDefFoundErro" would be thrown.